# Put Clear Icon Card Material-UI in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I put the clear icon on the card on the top right side of the card overlapping it.
What is the proper way to do it?

[image: So]

CLICK HERE = [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/simplepaper-material-demo-forked-jbgee?file=/demo.js)

```
<Paper
  sx={{
    padding: "1em",
    background: "black"
  }}
>
  <IconButton color="error" aria-label="add to shopping cart">
    <ClearIcon />
  </IconButton>
  <Grid
    component="div"
    container
    spacing={2}
    sx={{
      marginBottom: "1em"
    }}
  >
    <Grid component="div" item sm={12}>
      <Alert>SUCCESS</Alert>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Paper>;
```

Comment: you mean inside the alert box?

Comment: @I am L. no. between outside and inside. overlapping it

Comment: put clarity your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Paper
  sx={{
    padding: "1em",
    background: "black",
    position: "relative"
  }}
>
  <IconButton
    sx={{
      position: "absolute",
      top: "-15px",
      right: "-15px",

      // not necessary, just added this coz it looks weird
      background: "white"
    }}
    color="error"
    aria-label="add to shopping cart"
  >
    <ClearIcon />
  </IconButton>
  <Grid
    component="div"
    container
    spacing={2}
    sx={{
      marginBottom: "1em"
    }}
  >
    <Grid component="div" item sm={12}>
      <Alert>SUCCESS</Alert>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Paper>
```

What I did is simple, make the Paper position relative, then make the icon button absolute.

This way the button will follow whenever you move/animate the Paper.

The outcome would be something like this: https://wphyd.csb.app/

Comment: Not on the alert box. on the card itself